# how do I make analysis warnings trigger runtime failure

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

In the following example, *main* is allowed to call a *sniff* function on Dog that I would prefer would somehow break. If I say exactly what a Dog can do, but somehow the client knows more and can get the object to do more with that special knowledge - I think that is an encapsulation leak. I don't necessarily want it to die in the general case, but is there a flag or way to run that would enforce that only methods be called if they exist. I know the language supports the knowledge that something is wrong since the Dart Editor displays a warning: *The method 'sniff' is not defined for the class 'Dog'*. Even when run with *--checked* flag, this runs fine.

So suppose similar code were invoked by a test. Is there a flag in Dart or some code to cause it to fail when the test is run?

```dart
abstract class Dog {
  void run();
  void bark();
}

class BigDog implements Dog {
  void run() => print("Big dog running");
  void bark() => print("Woof");
  void sniff() => print("Sniff");
}

main() {
  Dog bd = new BigDog();
  bd.run();
  bd.bark();
  bd.sniff();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with restricting the scope to the library? `void _sniff()`

Comment: sniff is bad example, I should have used something only big dogs do. But, using private _sniff does not address the general problem. It's like saying, "here is a nice interface, go make all the derivatives you want, just make sure all methods you add are private". I don't want to stop the world from sniffing, just base Dog instances. The reason this came up is I had some thorough tests that were all passing, but I use emacs. I loaded project into Dart Editor and found the issues. I don't want to change the language, just automate a requirement for 0 or near 0 analysis warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure to run the tests in `checked mode` `dart -c testfile.dart` then type annotations are taken into account. You shouldn't use `checked mode` in production though because it slows down your application.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The problem is that your instance *really is* a `BigDog`; and therefore it *really has* a `sniff` method. An important goal in Dart is that [type annotations *do not* affect runtime behaviour](https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html#q-why-do-type-annotations-have-no-effect-on-the-runtime-behavior); therefore your `Dog` annotation is unable to change the behaviour.

The tooling is able to highlight this because it *does* use the type annotations.

This sort of question comes up a lot in the Dart bug tracker; but it would be a pretty fundamental change to allow type annotations to change behaviour, so it's not something I expect would ever be considered; confusing as it might be. [See here](https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html#q-why-do-type-annotations-have-no-effect-on-the-runtime-behavior) for some more info on this.